# Were the spear-fishing and green milk in TLJ added due to fear over fan nitpicking?

Tags: star-wars, the-last-jedi, behind-the-scenes, luke-skywalker

I don't really see the point of the montage involving Luke spearfishing and milking the space manatee.   I don't see much of a story-telling reason to see how Luke has survived or become very rugged.

> It's true that the opportunity to show his starfighter submerged was taken, and this serves to (falsely) foreshadow that he is actually on Crait.

However, this could have been achieved with any shot of the water.

Do we have any commentary from production staff about the reasoning behind this scene?  Any suggestion there was concern that if not depicted, fans would treat his survival as a plot hole?   Concern that people would assume he regularly left Ahch-To for provisions?

Comment: Conversation about plot holes in TLJ has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/86887/discussion-on-question-by-thepopmachine-were-the-spear-fishing-and-green-milk-in).

Comment: I took the montage as a way to characterize Luke's indifference to Rey. He just goes about his daily routine, undignified and arduous as it is, to drive the point home to Rey that he has no inclination or need to leave the planet. I don't know about the writers' intent for the scene, but it serves at least that purpose.